# GCP Identity platform integration with golang backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I am developing web platform which has to have 3 type of users (user, admin, partner companies). For the authentication I am considering to use google Identity platform with multitenancy (probably users in one tenant and admins are in different tenant).

As I understand from documentation, how do we integrate identity platform to our application is to create identity platform provider from console and integrate it into frontend with UI. From front-end, without contacting backend service we can sign up, login and logout by calling firebase SDK and it will give us authentication token. From backend I can check that token with middleware and decide if I agree the user as authenticated or not. Correct me if I am wrong.

Then I can get some metadata of authenticated user from the token, maybe email or name etc. But I want to store user related information on noSQL database as well. For example, if user wants to change his email I need to handle it in backend server, also, I'd like to store users log (access and audit log on somewhere else). In case of, I am using frontend UI and SDK how do log the access and audit information on my backend? also, when changing user's information, do I just write handler function in backend end update user's data with REST API or Admin SDK? what is the best practice over here? Or should I better write my own login and logout function on my backend then call REST API or Admin SDK? is there preferred way? Google is showing me only integration way of authentication from frontend?

BTW, I am deploying backend application on google cloud run, and frontend would be developed in react and should be deployed maybe in firebase or in cloud run as well.

Thanks

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Can you please check.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-authentication),Yes your understanding is correct to integrate identity platform to the application.

You can store the user related information on a noSQL database like Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database. You can write the Rest API to change or update the user's information in the database.

If you want to write your own login and logout function, I don’t think it is necessary because Firebase Admin SDK provides these features. But if you want to manage user authentication in the backend for specific requirements, you can write your own login and logout function on the backend and use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

For access and audit log information you can use [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/05/introducing-firebase-analytics), Firebase Analytics helps you understand what your users are doing in your app. It has all of the metrics that you’d expect in an app analytics tool combined with user properties like device type, app version, and OS version to give you insight into how users interact with your app.

But finally, the best way would depend on your requirements and use case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've halfway there your answer is correct, apart from login part. Can you double check if the admin SDK really offers login on the SDK. I didn't find any login option in SDK. Regarding to this matter, your answer seems correct, so I'll mark it accordingly.